# Making multiple web api calls synchronously without nesting in Node.js with Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Is there any way I can make the below code run synchronously in a way where I can get all of the productLine ids and then loop through and delete all of them, then once all of this is complete, get all of the productIds and then loop through and delete all of them?

I really want to be able to delete each set of items in batch, but the next section can't run until the first section is complete or there will be referential integrity issues.

```
// Delete Product Lines
axios.get('https://myapi.com/ProductLine?select=id')
    .then(function (response) {
        const ids = response.data.value

        ids.forEach(id => {
            axios.delete('https://myapi.com/ProductLine/' + id)
        })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {

    })

// Delete Products (I want to ensure this runs after the above code)
axios.get('https://myapi.com/Product?select=id')
    .then(function (response) {
        const ids = response.data.value

        ids.forEach(id => {
            axios.delete('https://myapi.com/Product/' + id)
        })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of duplication in your code. To reduce code duplication, you can create a helper function that can be called with appropriate arguments and this helper function will contain code to delete product lines and products.

```
async function deleteHelper(getURL, deleteURL) {
   const response = await axios.get(getURL);
   const ids = response.data.value;

   return Promise.all(ids.map(id => (
      axios.delete(deleteURL + id)
   )));
}
```

With this helper function, now your code will be simplified and will be without code duplication.

Now to achieve the desired result, you could use one of the following ways:

- Instead of two separate promise chains, use only one promise chain that deletes product lines and then deletes products.

  ```
  const prodLineGetURL = 'https://myapi.com/ProductLine?select=id';
  const prodLineDeleteURL = 'https://myapi.com/ProductLine/';

  deleteHelper(prodLineGetURL, prodLineDeleteURL)
    .then(function() {
       const prodGetURL = 'https://myapi.com/Product?select=id';
       const prodDeleteURL = 'https://myapi.com/Product/';
       deleteHelper(prodGetURL, prodDeleteURL);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
    });
  ```
- Use `async-await` syntax.

  ```
  async function delete() {
     try {
       const urls = [
          [ prodLineGetURL, prodLineDeleteURL ],
          [ prodGetURL, prodDeleteURL ]
       ];

       for (const [getURL, deleteURL] of urls) {
          await deleteHelper(getURL, deleteURL); 
       }

     } catch (error) {
       // handle error
     }
  }
  ```

One other thing that you could improve in your code is to use `Promise.all` instead of `forEach()` method to make delete requests, above code uses `Promise.all` inside `deleteHelper` function.

Comment: thank you so much! I am creating a CLI using node.js that makes a bunch of web api calls. Will I be able to use async-await since it is not part of CommonJS?

Comment: Yes you can use `async-await` syntax in nodejs. `CommonJS` is a module system, it has nothing to do with `async-await` syntax.

Comment: sorry about that, I know I was reading somewhere that async-await doesn't work in certain browsers or something like that. I am assuming I don't need to worry for a cli.

Comment: Support for `async-await` syntax is pretty good at this point but as your code won't be running in the browsers, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Quick question, in the deleteHelper I am doing the following: const ids = response.data.value.map(idObj => idObj.id) which is slightly different than your example. I need to call map since response.data.value is an array of objects such as [{"id": "1000"}, {"id": "2000"}, {"id": "2000"}]. Do I need to call await on this? The reason I ask is because I am still getting referencial integrity errors when trying to delete the Products as if all the ProductLine deletes didn't complete first. Is that even possible?

Comment: No, you don't need to use `await` before `response.data.value.map(...)` because this code is synchronous, it doesn't returns a promise. As far as your second question is concerned, code included in my answer will only delete products after request to delete product line has completed successfully.

Comment: For question 1, sorry about that, not sure what I was thinking. For question 2, it is very strange. I implemented all of this exactly like your example and I am still getting referencial integrity errors. Is there any possible change the ProductLines might not be deleted from the database fully by the time we start making the delete product requests? I am assuming this is all moving rapidly. When I comment out the Product delete and only run the ProductLine delete, then uncomment the ProductLine delete and run again it ends up working with no problem.

Comment: a bit more detail, the backend returns a 204 No content on successful delete. So I would assume as long as that is the case we have a success response and the promise.all will not complete if a single one of them returns an error response right?

Comment: Comment out the product delete code and when product line delete is completed, `.then()` block will execute that deletes the products. In the `.then()` bock, make a request to fetch the product line and see if everything has been deleted or not. If it has, then code is executing as it should. If you are using `async-await` instead of promise-chaining, then remove the loop and between the requests to delete product line and products, add a request that fetches product line, This will help you debug whether your code tries to delete products before product line has been deleted completely or not

Comment: thank you I am using async-await and have done the troubleshooting steps, I am sure i will eventually figure it out. One final question if you don't mind answering.. If I have a scenario where I am POSTING a message to an API and it kicks off a backend job but gives an immediate response. The only way for me to know that backend job is complete is by continuously running a query until I get the expected result. I would want to await the rest of the code until I get this result. Is there a certain way to do this with promises? It's almost like I want to await until a query result equals XYZ

Comment: Promises can only be used to wait for the result of a single async operation. You can't use a single promise to wait for the result of multiple async operations because once the promise is settled, its done. It can't be reused.

Comment: Then I suppose my only option is to use a timer and keep querying until I see the expected result right?

Answer (score 1):

Your code (and all other answers) are executing `delete` requests sequentially, which is **huge waste of time**. You should use `Promise.all()` and execute in parallel...

```js
// Delete Product Lines
axios.get('https://myapi.com/ProductLine?select=id')
    .then(function (response) {
        const ids = response.data.value

        // execute all delete requests in parallel
        Promise.all(
          ids.map(id => axios.delete('https://myapi.com/ProductLine/' + id))
        ).then(
          // all delete request are finished
        );        
    })
    .catch(function (error) {

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

All HTTP request are asynchronous but you can make it sync-like. How? Using [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Suppose you have a function called `retrieveProducts`, you need to make that function `async` and then `await` for the response to keep processing.

Leaving it to:

```
const retrieveProducts = async () => {

// Delete Product Lines
const response = await axios.get('https://myapi.com/ProductLine?select=id')
const ids = response.data.value
ids.forEach(id => {
  axios.delete('https://myapi.com/ProductLine/' + id)
})

// Delete Products (I want to ensure this runs after the above code)
const otherResponse = await axios.get('https://myapi.com/Product?select=id') // use proper var name
const otherIds = response.data.value //same here
otherIds.forEach(id => {
  axios.delete('https://myapi.com/Product/' + id)
})
}
```

But just keep in mind that it's not synchronous, it keeps being async

Comment: Not a good solutioon. All `delete` requests are executed sequentially